# Trying to use properties file in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a locations.properties file which looks like this:

```
location.endpoint=testadres,andertestadres
location.test=teststring
```

I'm trying to read this config file with following class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:locations.properties")
public class LocationProperties {

@Value("#{'${location.endpoint}'.split(',')}")
private List<String> locations;

@Value("${location.test}")
private String test;

public String getTest() {
    return this.test;
}

public List<String> getLocations() {
    return this.locations;
}

//To resolve ${} in @Value
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
}
```

But whenever I try to get the strings with getLocations() or getTest() I get null?

Comment: try with `"classpath*:locations.properties"`

Comment: @prashantthakre if I do that I get: class path resource [*/locations.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: @Philipe I just modified my comment , can you try with using wild card as mentioned in my above comments

Comment: @prashantthakre still doensn't work. File not found error.So with my code above, the file is found, the values are just not getting read.

Comment: I just copied your code into one of my spring boot projects and it works fine here. The `propertyConfigInDev` bean also doesn't seem to be needed. Can you paste the code you use to call `getTest` / `getLocations`?

Answer (score 0):

Just add .properties or .yml file to your /resources folder. Example

```
# simple.yml
demo:
connection:
    username: sample
    sample: My text
```

and add POJO class

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(
prefix = "demo.connection", 
locations = "classpath:sample.yml"
)
public class SampleSettings {

private String sample;

private String username;

..Getters and Setters mandatory
```